# « Le/la/les voilà de + verbe infinitif »

Tags: verbes, constructions, france

Ce tour provient de *la Petite Fadette* (George Sand). Il permet de faire une phrase sans verbe conjugué. Est-ce qu'il est toujours utilisable de nos jours ?

> Le voilà donc de courir jusqu'à la demeurance de la mère Fadet et de lui conter sa peine
> en la priant de venir jusqu'à la coupure avec lui, pour essayer par son secret de lui faire
> retrouver son frère vivant ou mort.

Answer (score 2):

*Est-ce qu'il est toujours utilisable de nos jours ?*

Oui, bien sûr, qu'est-ce qui l'interdirait ?

> *Concert de haute volée, en effet, d’un humour volontairement décalé, réunissant pour les besoins du synopsis Claudio Monteverdi et Samuel Scheidt. Deux immenses « pointures » reconnues et adulées, rentrant d’une soirée particulièrement arrosée… **Et les voilà de se demander** qui, de nous deux, sera le plus fameux de sa génération ?*
>
> [L'Alsace, 1<sup>er</sup> mars 2019](https://www.lalsace.fr/haut-rhin/2019/03/01/popstars-en-baroquie).

Comment: Il me semble que la conjonction change tout ; le tour « et de » permet déjà de construire une phrase avec un infinitif. De plus, je trouve que « le voilà de + infinitif » ferait parti du parler paysan à une certaine époque, par exemple chez Marcel Aymé ([parler paysan](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_parler_paysan_dans_les_romans_de_Marc/DVQnAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22le+voil%C3%A0+de%22&dq=%22le+voil%C3%A0+de%22&printsec=frontcover)).

Comment: *Le voilà-t-y pas qui chipote pour une conjonction !* :-)